# How can I handle redirection if someone tries a unexisting route on a Symfony 5 project

Tags: php, redirect, routes, symfony5

How can I avoid giving the red alert page when someone tries to get to an unexisting route and just redirect them to the homepage instead ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html) about handling error pages.

In your use case you can choose from:

- [override the default error controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#custom-error-controller):

  ```yaml
  # config/packages/framework.yaml
  framework:
    # implement controller / action and return a RedirectReponse from there
    error_controller: App\Controller\ErrorController::show
  ```
- [handle the kernel.exception event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#use-kernel-exception-event):

  ```php
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

  class ControllerListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
  {
      public static function getSubscribedEvents()
      {
          return [
              KernelEvents::EXCEPTION=> 'onException',
          ];
      }

      public function onException(ExceptionEvent $event)
      {
          // implement custom logic and set your response, eg.:
          // $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(...))
      }
  }
  ```