# Is it possible to make a fallback route if other routes was not found

Tags: symfony4

Is it possible to make such a configuration in Symfony 4 that will route a request after all other route rules were checked to a fallback controller action?

Please, advise with a working example.

I have checked [Symfony 4.4 documentation on routing](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/routing.html) and haven't found a working solution yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I handle redirection if someone tries a unexisting route on a Symfony 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135385/how-can-i-handle-redirection-if-someone-tries-a-unexisting-route-on-a-symfony-5)

Comment: @JimmyBlu thank you. I don't want to deal with Exceptions. I have found another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with Symfony Route annotation in the method comment setion that works for me fine:

```
* @Route("/{slug}", methods={"GET"}, name="shortlink_product_detail", options={"expose"=true,"priority"=9})
```

Also, do not forget to add use in the top of your PHP class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

Comment: You can see your added route running the command:
bin/console debug:router

Comment: Route priority was added in [5.1](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#priority-parameter) whereas the original question was about Symfony 4.4.

Comment: Thank you @JimmyBlu I see the documentation. Now I have to check why it works on my Symfony 4.4 web application as well

Comment: Propably you defined the route as last one? "Fallback" by accident in your case - but critical in symfony. You can always dump (the order) of your routes by using command you already know: `bin/console debug:router`